# Python how to split and join chars of characters in a list

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I am trying to output the list as below but the only list I was able to create is a list of chars. Could someone please point me to the right direction please. I cannot use `regex` here.

Content of doc.txt file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Testing tags only</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Code:

```
with open('doc.txt', 'r') as f:
    empty_tag_list = []
    # loop through all lines using f.readlines() method
    for line in f.readlines():
        new_line = []
        # this is how you would loop through each alphabet
        isTag = False
        for chars in line:
            if chars =="<":
                isTag = True
            if isTag ==True:
                empty_tag_list.append(chars)
            if chars ==">":
                isTag = False
                empty_tag_list.append(new_line)
                empty_tag_list.remove("<")
                empty_tag_list.remove(">")
    print(empty_tag_list)
```

Output:

```
['h', 't', 'm', 'l', [], 'h', 'e', 'a', 'd', [], 't', 'i', 't', 'l', 'e', [], '/', 't', 'i', 't', 'l', 'e', [], '/', 'h', 'e', 'a', 'd', [], 'b', 'o', 'd', 'y', [], '/', 'b', 'o', 'd', 'y', [], '/', 'h', 't', 'm', 'l', []]
```

How can I have the output as :

```
[html,head,title,/title,/head,body,/body,/html]
```

Comment: can you edit your post with example of content of your original file ?

Comment: Have you tried just using a regex like `re.findall(r'<(/?\w+).*?>', text)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should concatenate new characters to a string instead of appending them to a list. Only append a new string to the output list at the start of a tag:

```
with open('doc.txt', 'r') as f:
    empty_tag_list = []
    for line in f:
        isTag = False
        for chars in line:
            if chars == "<":
                isTag = True
                empty_tag_list.append('')
            elif chars == ">":
                isTag = False
            elif isTag:
                empty_tag_list[-1] += chars
    print(empty_tag_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, you want a `list` of tags, you can do the following:

```
for line in f.readlines():
    new_line = ''
    isTag = False
    for char in line:
        if char == "<":
            isTag = True
        elif char == ">":
            isTag = False
            empty_tag_list.append(new_line)
            new_line = ''
        elif isTag:
            new_line += char
print(empty_tag_list)
# ['html', 'head', 'title', '/title', '/head', 'body', '/body', '/html']
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manually iterating and checking each character, I'd suggest using a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

```
import re
with open("doc.txt") as f:
    text = "".join(f)
    tags = re.findall(r'<(/?\w+).*?>', text)
```

Here, `<(/?\w+).*?>` means `<` followed by optional `/` and word-characters (to be kept), then optionally more stuff, and a `>`. Afterwards, `tags` is `['html', 'head', 'title', '/title', '/head', 'body', '/body', '/html']`.

For more complex tasks you could also consider using a proper HTML parser like Beautiful Soup, but for this, regex might be good enough.